# Cuadrado mágico c++

Tags: c++, matrices

Este es mi código, solo necesito una idea para como eliminar números del cuadrado mágico aleatoriamente y asi ser ingresados por el usuario.

```
int main()
{
int m[11][11];
int v[12];
int op,c=0, x=0, y=0, k=0;
gotoxy(48,0);
cout<<"CUADRADO MAGICO"<<endl;
cout<<"Tamano del cuadradro magico"<<endl<<"1.5x5"<<endl<<"2.11x11"<<endl;
cout<<"Tamano...";
cin>>op;
if(op==1) //cuadro magico 5*5
{
 system("cls");
 cout<<endl;
  m[5][5];
  int fil,col;
  memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));
  int i =0 ;
  int j= 5/2;
  for ( int x=1;x<=5*5;x++ )
  {
     m[i][j]= x;
     fil=(i+1)%5;
     col=(j+1)%5;
     if (m[fil][col] == 0)
     {
        i=fil;
        j=col;
     }
     else
     {
        i=(i-1+5)%5;
     }
  }
  for(int f=0;f<5;f++)
  {
     for(int c=0;c<5;c++)
         {
         cout<<m[f][c]<<" ";
      }
         cout<<"\n";
  }

do //mover cursor
 {
c=_getch();
if(c==97)
 x--;
if(c==100)
 x++;
if(c==119)
 y--;
if(c==115)
 y++;

  gotoxy(x,y);
  cout<<"";
  k++;
} while(c!=46);

 _getch();
  system("cls");


}
if(op==2)//cuadro magico 11*11
{
  system("cls");
 cout<<endl;
  m[11][11];
  int fil,col;
  memset(m, 0, sizeof(m));
  int i =0 ;
  int j= 11/2;
  for ( int x=1;x<=11*11;x++ )
  {
     m[i][j]= x;
     fil=(i+1)%11;
     col=(j+1)%11;
     if (m[fil][col] == 0)
     {
        i=fil;
        j=col;
     }
     else
     {
        i=(i-1+11)%11;
     }
  }
  for(int f=0;f<11;f++)
  {
     for(int c=0;c<11;c++)
         cout<<m[f][c]<<" ";
     cout<<endl;
  }
do //mover cursor
 {
c=_getch();
if(c==97)
 x--;
if(c==100)
 x++;
if(c==119)
 y--;
if(c==115)
 y++;

  gotoxy(x,y);
  cout<<"";
  k++;
} while(c!=46);
getch();
  system("cls");
}


_getch();
return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

La función `(rand()%[valor numérico]))` es la función que se utiliza en C para generar un número "pseudoaleatorio" y el valor numérico-1 es máximo valor que alcanzará el número mostrado.
Habría que verlo como implementar dicha función en el código.
Más información [C – round() function](http://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-arithmetic-functions/c-round-function/)